# Why does RocketMQ not support JMS 2.0?

Tags: jms, rocketmq

I wonder why RocketMQ does not support JMS 2.0? As we all know JMS 2.0 is a common stardard for mq. If RocketMQ supported JMS 2.0 it could connect with other mq products easily.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response and thanks for your attention to RocketMQ. We actually had an external project doing JMS thing before, where you could find it in this repo: [rocketmq-jms](https://github.com/apache/rocketmq-externals/tree/master/rocketmq-jms), but seems like the contributor did not maintain it for a while.

We are now encouraging more developers to join our community and try RocketMQ out. It would be even better if making some contributions. You could maybe try opening a Issue/PR for your requests if you like.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).